# Reddit bot running in to limit despite setting limit=None

Tags: praw

I am trying to get a large amount of comments with PRAW in a python Reddit bot. I know that the absolute limit of submissions you can get is 1000, with the default being 100. I use this line of code below to get the comments:

```
for comment in r.redditor(raw_username).comments.new(limit=None):
```

As you can see I have set limit=None but I can still only get 100 comments at a time. Why is this? I have looked elsewhere but all the answers I could find were people wanting to go over the 1000 limit. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it still gets limited if used too much. Waiting for a bit fixed it.